# When does a group and its pro-algebraic completion have equivalent categories of arbitrary representations?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, algebraic-groups, tannakian-category

In the following everything is over some field $k$.

Let $G$ be a discrete group. We write $G^{\text{alg}}$ for its *pro-algebraic completion*. The latter is a pro-affine pro-algebraic group which arises as the Tannakian dual to the category $\mathrm{Rep}_{\text{fd}}(G)$ of finite-dimensional $G$-representations. By definition there is an equivalence of categories
$$
\mathrm{Rep}_{\text{fd}}(G)\simeq \mathrm{Rep}_{\text{fd}}(G^\text{alg}).
$$
Under what conditions does this lift to an equivalence of categories of possibly-infinite dimensional representations?

Comment: For the usual story, I think you want finite dim representations such that $G^{alg}\to Gl_n(k)$ is a morphism of group schemes. I sort of doubt there is a useful statement for infinite dim reps, unless $G$ is finite of corse.

Comment: Is it possible that finiteness is necessary? Certainly Rep(G) (infinite dim) recovers G, and  Rep(G^alg) recovers G^alg (it's just the ind-completion I think), so if the two are equivalent doesn't that say G and G^alg are iso as group schemes?

Comment: I agree $Rep(G{alg})$ should be the ind-completion, What concerns me is that this may not contain the regular representation of G, when it’s infinite.

Comment: Right, but the finite dimensional representations are already enough to recover G^alg, by definition, so what's the issue?  Maybe I'm missing something obvious

Comment: The issue is whether $Rep(G^{alg})=Rep(G)$. I thought that’s what you wanted.

Comment: If the definition of infinite-dimensional representation of $G^{alg}$ is what I think it is, then it sounds to me like the answer is "iff $G$ is finite" precisely for the reason Donu points at: the regular representation of $G$ won't be a representation of $G^{alg}$ because it will fail to be a filtered colimit of finite-dimensional representations. Right?